# TipTip jQuery Plugin not working?

Tags: jquery, tiptip

I have a question ..

Simple really .. I'm trying to use TipTip, but for some reason its not working for me..

Here the JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".someClass").tipTip();
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>
Cras sed ante. Phasellus in massa. <a href="" class="someClass" title="This will show up in the TipTip popup.">Curabitur dolor eros</a>, gravida et, hendrerit ac, cursus non, massa.
</p>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/z2LFB/1/

Also, on another page where I've seem TipTip is being used, two tooltips display .. One is the native tooltip, and one is the TipTip one .. How can I hide out the native tooltip and only show the TipTip one ?

Comment: fiddle doesnt make sense when you dont include plugin :)

Comment: Its working for me - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2LFB/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the TipTip js:
    `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drewwilson/TipTip/master/jquery.tipTip.minified.js`

Here is your fiddle updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/aembleton/mnLg9t3k/1/